There is a cable that takes the phone to recovery mode?
There is a cable to take the Samsung phone to recovery mode. Like the jig cable that takes the Samsung phone to download mode.
The tp cable automatically takes the Huawei phone to recovery mode. The engineering cable takes the iPhone to recovery mode and dfu mode for flashing and repair. There are other cables for iPhone, jitogxue, isoft, magico, iboot, idfu, and idfu go to dfu mode. For Samsung phone, I don't know what cable goes to recovery mode.

Even if I find the topic quite interesting, especially the examples you have mentioned I feat the question is too generic at the moment. Those cables work because in the phone special hardware is used. As the hardware level is not standardized in Android there can be cables that work with certain devices but nothing in general that just works with any Android phone. Just to add to your collection: for older Google phones (e.g. Nexus 5x) Kernel/serial debugging cables exist.

Considering your previous posts I guess you want TK enter recovery mode because of your storage problem. Usually devices can be booted into recovery by holding volume down key at boot. But on a stock device I don't think recovery will be if much help as it's does not allow to access storage and delete files interactive.

I hold the buttons, it does not go to recovery mode.
I clear the cache of the hard drive in the recovery mode and activate the adb of the phone in the recovery mode.
It must be a cable that brings the Samsung phone to recovery mode.

You can not enable adb from within stock recovery. And the cache is if I am not mistaken on a separate partition. So I am not sure if it will have an effect on your "storage full problem".

You have a solution to boot the phone to the system.
I have to access the phone's storage hard drive. The phone files are very important to me. please help.
